# Is there a way to launch a beam job using the flink backend on yarn programmatically?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

Is there a way to launch a beam job using the flink backend on yarn programmatically? Can FlinkPipelineOptions be configured to point to a yarn cluster?